# Multiple operations on java object using Stream and lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

i have `class A {int sNo; String name;}` with valid constructor.
i need to trim name and sort on the basis of name using stream API.

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    ArrayList<A> l = new ArrayList();
    l.add(new A(1, " 1name "));
    l.add(new A(7, " 3name "));
    l.add(new A(6, ""));
    l.add(new A(5, " 2name "));
    l.add(new A(4, " 5name "));
    l.add(new A(2, ""));

    List<String> i = l.stream()
            .filter(s -> !s.name.isEmpty())
            .map(s -> s.name.trim())
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(i); 
}
```

}

it is returning only name in sorted order

```
[, 1name, 2name, 3name, 5name]
```

but i need entire object.

i know `s -> s.name.trim()` is the reason its storing name only,

how can apply operation on particular filed but store entire object.

Comment: thanks @janos for your reply , yes its working fine but i have a small doubt. s -> new A(s.sNo, s.name.trim())) is not scalable , i mean in this example class A containing 2 variables only so its ok to call its constructor, but if class A has lets say 20-30 variables then it is not wise to call constructor with all same values and just i updated 1, is there any work around??

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, not because it's particularly nice or even recommended. One could accomplish that also with anonymous Objects:

```
    List<A> i = l.stream()
            .filter(s -> !s.name.isEmpty())
            .map(s -> new Object() {A a = s; String name = s.name.trim();})
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.name))
            .map(o -> o.a)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Not every compiler will be happy about this (`javac` will), but it's valid Java code.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `map` function you are converting all your objects into strings, so instead of map, use for each to transform the strings inside the object but not returning a lists of strings :

```
 class A {
 int sNo; 
 String name;

 public int getName(){ return name}



 public void setName(String name){ this.name = name;}

  }

i.forEach(s -> s.setName(s.getName().trim()));

List<A> i = l.stream()
        .filter(s -> !s.name.isEmpty())       
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.name))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What do you believe `forEach(s -> s.name.trim())` does? I mean, other than use up the CPU?

Comment: @Andreas you're right, forgot to set the value to update the object state

Comment: `s` doesn't have a `setName()` method. Or, if it does, it likely also has a `getName()` method.

Comment: @Andreas of course of course, forgot to add that important detail too, I updated again. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> it is returning only name in sorted order [...] but i need entire object.

The `.map(s -> s.name.trim())` step transforms your stream of `A` into a stream of `String`. That's why you're left with strings, instead of entire objects.

If you want a sorted list of objects, then the result should be in a `List<A>` and not in a `List<String>`.

To sort a list of objects by a field, you can pass a `Comparator` to `sorted`.

```
List<A> result = l.stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.name.isEmpty())
    .map(s -> new A(s.sNo, s.name.trim()))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.name))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you don't want to create a `new A` with the trimmed name,
but want to modify the original object (though I seriously doubt that),
you can replace the `map` step with `peek` and modify the object:

```
.peek(s -> s.name = s.name.trim())
```

However, note that as @Mustafa pointed out, `peek` is intended only for debugging. And in fact if you want to modify the underlying objects, it would be better to that in a step separate from the filtering and sorting,
as it is a logically unrelated step anyway (it looks like data cleaning).
That step can be implemented using `forEach`.

If you don't actually need to trim the name (thanks @Andreas for the hint),
only for the purpose of sorting,
then you can drop the `map` step entirely,
and write the `sorted` step like this:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.name.trim()))
```

Comment: You could just do `sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.name.trim()))`. Sure, it's not good for performance, but it works and eliminates the need for `map()`.

Comment: @Andreas I was under the impression that OP actually wants to trim the string, not only sort on the trimmed value. But your idea is more likely, thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: Creating new objects is better, otherwise the use of `forEach` is recommended over `peek`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-), `peek` is only meant for debugging.

Comment: thanks @janos for your reply , yes its working fine but i have a small doubt.
s -> new A(s.sNo, s.name.trim())) is not scalable , i mean in this example class A containing 2 variables only so its ok to call its constructor, but if class A has lets say 20-30 variables then it is not wise to call constructor with all same values and just i updated 1,
is there any work around??